# How to find price swing from option chart?

Tags: options, stock-analysis

I'm reading the article https://seekingalpha.com/article/4389159-nio-behind-this-wild-pre-earnings-rally but don't understand some of the calculations and terms used in the article.

Could someone help me to understand?

1. Where can I find the IV is 200% in the Options Chain?
   `Options are pricing in a significantly large move, with IV over 200% for Nov. 20 expiry`
2. How do we find from the Options chart that there would be a $10 move?
   `At and near the money options for November 20 are pointing to a nearly $10 move by the end of next week, as implied volatility sits at over 200%.`
3. How to calculate the price swing between $60 and $30? `December options were also feeling the effects of high IV; yet volume here is heavy in calls. Since there are more days to expiration, implied move is up to nearly $16 - any near the money strangle would be pointing to break-evens around $60 or higher or around $30 or lower.`
4. What is short squeeze?
   `Yet this NIO rally isn't fueled by a short squeeze`

Comment: What is the meaning of the text in `inline code` format? Are those your own comments that elaborate on each question?

Comment: I am sorry. Questions of the form "Please read this entire article for context and answer these questions," are not really good for this stack. The quotes are appreciated, but not enough context.  As I look at this question, it can probably be broken up into 2 on topic ones, with the rest of it too specific, or really just 'not available'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where can I find the IV is 200% in the Options Chain? Options are pricing in a significantly large move, with IV over 200% for Nov. 20 expiry

Any decent broker will provide the implied volatility for options.  Here's an [example](https://researchtools.fidelity.com/ftgw/mloptions/goto/optionChain?symbols=TRIT).  Some web sites also offer this though they tend to be delayed quotes during the day or EOD quotes.  For [example](https://www.optionistics.com/quotes/stock-option-chains).

If you like DIY, you can also use an option pricing model (web site or Excel).

> How do we find from the Options chart that there would be a $10 move? At and near the money options for November 20 are pointing to a nearly $10 move by the end of next week, as implied volatility sits at over 200%.

Here's an article that describes [Converting Implied Volatility to Expected Daily Move](https://www.macroption.com/converting-implied-volatility-to-daily-move/).  I offer no commentary since this isn't relevant to my trading.

> How to calculate the price swing between $60 and $30? December options were also feeling the effects of high IV; yet volume here is heavy in calls. Since there are more days to expiration, implied move is up to nearly $16 - any near the money strangle would be pointing to break-evens around $60 or higher or around $30 or lower.

See the previous paragraph.

> What is short squeeze? Yet this NIO rally isn't fueled by a short squeeze.

Google "Short Squeeze" and you'll find plenty of explanations.